# When I run the appium code getting error like "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ios, eclipse, appium

" Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65"

When I run the code in ios mac machine for ios automation by using appium+eclipse, getting the error like Unknown server side error

I'm using the versions of 
xcode version:10.1
appium version:1.13.1

Application has to run properly without errors and launch the application

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run automated tests on a real iOS device but you haven't configured the necessary [provisioning profile in XCode](https://ioscodesigning.com/generating-code-signing-files/)

The steps you should take are comprehensively described in the [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/) article, you will need to set up a developer account in XCode and configure code signing for WebDriverAgentRunner

Alternatively you might find [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) tool useful, it provides easy GUI wizard which will guide you through the process of creating developer account and configuring code signing for WebDriverAgentRunner project which is a pre-requisite for Appium tests execution on real devices.